# Is there any major performance issue if you switch default-storage-engine setting from InnoDB to MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, database-administration, mysql8

Recently we upgraded version of MySQL on the database server, Almost all of our tables are in MyISAM but in my.ini we have set

```
--default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

But now we want to change this setting to MyISAM because previously we were using MyISAM as a default engine

```
--default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Is changing default-storage-engine on the fly is a good practice? Will it work? Even if it works, Will there be any major performance issues?

It's the legacy application for which we are using this database that is the reason almost all tables are using the **MyISAM** engine. We are not using DB transactions anywhere in the application.

MySQL Version : 8.0
OS: Windows Server

Answer (score 2):

Changing the default storage engine affects only new tables that are created with `CREATE TABLE` statement, without specifying database engine.

So, unless you plan to create new tables, there is no difference which setting you have in configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

If multiple queries could run at the same time (e.g. multi user environment), then you should plan moving to InnoDB for all tables. I would also run MySQL on a Linux machine.

To change the engine, you should export the database with mysqldump, then change the engine in the dump and import it back. You can also use `ALTER TABLE mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;` for each table of your schema. Do not change the DB engine for `mysql` schema.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM does not have transaction ACID properties. I would switch to InnoBD. I may be mistaken.

Comment: Currently, we are not using or intend to use database transactions in the application as it's a legacy application and no active development is being done.

Comment: Even if you are not using transactions I would still use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

`default_storage_engine` applies only to newly created tables.  That is, changing the setting will not change existing tables.

To actually change tables, use `ALTER TABLE name ENGINE=engine` (for each table).

Do either of these before and after the conversion to assure yourself that the conversion happened:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;   -- has a column for "engine"

SHOW CREATE TABLE name;   -- shows the engine= clause at the end
```

Perhaps the only task that is likely to be significantly slower in InnoDB is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM name;
```

with no `WHERE` clause.  Do you use that a lot?  We can discuss workarounds.  Ditto for any other query that you identify is being slower.

I strongly encourage you to migrate to InnoDB before it is removed from MySQL.  Migration issues:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb